# Extract Page number from a web page using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

i wanted to get the total number of pages in a website. so what i did is that i tried to extract the page number in the bottom to calculate the total pages so that i can traverse using the Next Page Button. Please find the code i tried below :

```
totpage=driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH of the Page Number Shown in the Bottom of the Page")
print(page.text)
```

but the above code is printing the result as **0 of 0** instead of **1 - 200 of 900**

Please find the HTML code below :

```
<div class="mat-paginator-range-range-label"> 1 - 200 of 900 </div>
```

i was thinking to to do the calaulation as  , page = 900/200 after extracting the number.

what did i do wrong?

is there any alternative way to do this?,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I suggest add a delay before fetching that div, some pages I have seen, show 0 of 0 first time then in a moment update the real value.

Comment: Can you show us by snapshot or page url that how many node does your xpath matches in HTMLDOM ?

Comment: how to show the snapshot?

Comment: ok great i think the delay worked... now i  need to calculate the pages....

Answer (score 1):

Since you were able to solve `0 of 0 instead of 1 - 200 of 900` with delay. The other half of the problem can be solved by below logic. You should assign the variable that you've (using .text you must have got value 1 - 200 of 900) to `actual_count_page` .

```
actual_count_page = " 1 - 200 of 900 "
a = actual_count_page.strip().split(' ')
total_page_count = int(a[4])
max_number_count = int(a[2])

toal_number_of_pages = int(total_page_count/max_number_count)  + 1
print(toal_number_of_pages)
```